# Minecraft fake demo popup?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was bored, and started to watch random Minecraft videos. I happened to stumble upon [this video](https://youtu.be/wU6C4RuHKmE). How do you do this? Is this a command, plugin, datapack, or something else?

Comment: Which part of the video are you referring to?

Comment: And please not only link to the relevant part of the video, but describe what you're referring to.

Comment: ...because otherwise this question loses all meaning if the video ever gets deleted or set to private, which could happen any moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a trolling plugin. You can see the command he runs before the GUI appears, '/troll badboyhalo demomenu'

Answer (score -3):

this is easy to set up. its not a command pack you do hvae u set a command for it, but it all done server side using command, not playes Mc in years there migt even be a UI for it now,

obviusly only admins have total control over it..

Comment: Can you please use correct punctuation, syntax, and ..words? Also, you don't answer the question, you merely give your thoughts on a possible approach.